# making my DIv Responsive

Tags: html, css, .net

I Have One Div Which is Again Divided into 3 Div's. I Want to make these Div's responsive.
Snippet is given Below . Also I tried to Make Position Relative but this is not Working.

```css
#upleft {
  width: 34%;
  height: 336px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#upright {
  width: 33%;
  height: 336px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#below {
  height: 337px;
  width: 33%;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 317px;
  background: #f3f3f3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 9px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 181px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 338px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div id="upleft">a1</div>
  <div id="upright">a2</div>
  <div id="below">a3</div>
</div>
```

please help

Comment: what do you mean by responsive? How do you want it to look in different devices?

Comment: Try reader [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). That framework can help you in creating a responsive website

Comment: yes, Syfer i Want to display these div's properly on any Device

Comment: I Will Try it Sweller, than You

Comment: You should try Bootstrap Grid System. I hope it will help you.

Comment: How do you want to show layout ?

Comment: I Want To Show These 3 Div's Horizantally After Screen Size Changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries:

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  #upleft { width: 100%; }
  #upright { width: 100%; }
  #below { width: 100%; }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  #upleft { width: 34%; }
  #upright { width: 33%; }
  #below { width: 33%; }
}
#upleft {
  height: 336px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#upright {
  height: 336px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#below {
  height: 337px;
  background: green;
  float : left;
  position: relative;
}
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 317px;
  background: #f3f3f3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 9px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 181px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 338px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , But I Want to Show These Divs Horizantally , plz help

Comment: make #below float:left and they'll be horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Change `position:relative;` in CSS of `.test` to `position:absolute;`.

```
.test{
   ...
    position: absolute;
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid layout. You can define multiple widths for screen sizes : [RWD](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

> col-lg : large screen
>
> col-md : middle screen
>
> col-xs : small screen

```css
#upleft {
  width: 34%;
  height: 336px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#upright {
  width: 33%;
  height: 336px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#below {
  height: 337px;
  width: 33%;
  background: green;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 317px;
  background: #f3f3f3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 9px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 181px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 338px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div id="upleft" class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">a1</div>
  <div id="upright" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8">a2</div>
  <div id="below" class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">a3</div>
</div>
```